# Dynamically updating app icon in OSX

Tags: macos, dynamic, icons, badge

When I was using Chrome to download something in Lion, a badge with downloading progress which dynamically updates itself is shown on my dock.

[image: Dynamic badge]

How may one go about achieving that?

Comment: Hey will was the `setBadgeLabel` able to do what you wanted? I thought `setBadgeLabel` was only for text, the circular progess in the bottom right of the Google Chrome icon looks like an image. Were you able to place an image over the icon with `setBadgeLabel`? Can you share a screenshot of your final result pleast.

Comment: If anyone needs a progress badge like the one in the above screenshot, I made a package for that: https://github.com/sindresorhus/DockProgress#badge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this piece of code:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile] setBadgeLabel:@"My String"];
```

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can find all the information you need (it's the [NSDockTile Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).